# image map jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, imagemap

I have an image with various image maps, eg:

```
<map id="rade_img_map_1335199662212" name="rade_img_map_1335199662212">
<area href="http://" coords="10,10,160,47" shape="RECT" /></map>
```

How can i add an inline style using jquery to my ul li

```
<ul id="level3">
<li>Test</li>
<li>rwer</li>
<li>wer</li>
<li>sdf</li>
```

So if the above image map is for `Test` how can i fire the jquery on hover? If i set the href for each of the image maps then i can read the values using jquery?

edit i have tried this, but i cant get the class to remove when not hovered:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#rade_img_map_1335199662212").hover(function () {
          $("li#rs1").removeClass("active");  //Make sure no other "active" classes exist
          $(this).addClass("active");  //Add the active class to the area that was clicked
      });
  });
```

Comment: image map is for images, where is your image?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. What are you trying to do on hover? What are you hovering over? How does the ul relate to the image map?

Comment: this sounds very blurry, can you give us a jsfiddle or some example or specify further what you want to do

Comment: Oh I get it, list items are images. Wut.